# How does Union-Find relate or differ to Graphs?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory, disjoint-sets

I understand that the former is a [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) while the latter is a [mathematical structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph).

But when implemented, they seem to share many of the same features and behaviors.

Each element in the disjoint-set can be considered a vertex in a graph. With the edges in the graph representing a set in Union-Find.

After reviewing http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/ and http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/42digraph/

I believe both can answer questions such as:

- Are these two elements/vertices connected?
- Is there a cycle?

So is there a greater difference between the two that I'm not seeing? 
When should I choose to use one over the other?

I see that a graph algorithm can use the Union-Find structure internally
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/43mst/KruskalMST.java.html

An implementation detail, but if Union-Find is faster, why use Depth-First Search to test for cycles? http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/DirectedCycle.java.html

Comment: You can use the Union Find data structure to test if adding a new edge creates a cycle in O(logN). Suppose U and V are connected and you can check this using Union Find in O(logN), then, if you add a new edge U-V, you are surely creating a cycle, and if U and V are not connected, you are surely not creating a cycle. So we can test M edges in O(MlogN). If we use DFS, we have to run a new search for every added edge, so the complexity for testing M edges will be O(M*(N+M)) which is not good at all.

Comment: @LucasSampaio Concise explanation! Also, per query cost of Union-Find can be optimized to O(\alpha(N)), so the complexity for testing M edges in Union-Find can be O(M \alpha(N))

Answer (score 3):

Union find is a data structure for dynamic connectivity problems, for example, when you are connecting edges one by one at runtime and want to know if there is a connection. Think of a maze or liquid percolation.
Also, in dynamic connectivity problems, you are usually dealing with sets of distinct items. You are essentially building equivalence classes. In many graph problems, however, you are looking for a path, or a connected component.

So to answer your question, if you are dealing with disjoint sets or problems that add/remove edges and want to see when the system is connected or how many connected items are there, use union-find. Otherwise, graph algorithms like DFS/BFS may be faster and easier to implement.

Comment: Complementing your answer, a common use case for the Union Find structure is the Kruskal Algorithm. In this algorithm we use the structure to keep track of dynamic connected components that will merge until we are left with a minimum spanning tree of the original graph